# Postgres get count but group by another column

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table like

```
customer liked
1        true
2        true
3        true
1        true
2        false
```

How can I count the total liked but group by customer, so I end up with something like:

```
customer total_likes
1        2
2        1
3        1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and a condition `COUNT` should do:

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(CASE WHEN liked = 'true' THEN 1 END) AS likes
FROM yourtable
group by customer
```

if it's a boolean column, do:

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(CASE WHEN liked THEN 1 END) AS likes
FROM yourtable
group by customer
```

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres, you can use the shorthand for conversion from a boolean to an integer:

```
select customer, sum(liked::int) as total_likes
from t
group by customer;
```

Note that this will return *all customers*, not only those with likes.  If you only want customers with likes, then a `where` clause is appropriate:

```
select customer, count(*)
from t
where liked
group by customer;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(LIKED) AS TOTAL_LIKES
FROM TABLE
WHERE LIKED = 'true'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
```

Comment: Thanks for this, would this allow counting against multiple columns? So if I added a third column I could get the total to include that as well? I have tried COUNT(liked AND some_other_column) which doesnt seem to affect the totals

Comment: You can use COUNT(*) , and in WHERE clause you filter the results you want

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `liked` is a boolean type field,

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(liked) AS total_likes
FROM table_name 
WHERE liked is true
GROUP BY customer
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` statement inside of a `COUNT` function.

```
SELECT customer, COUNT(CASE WHEN liked = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS total_likes
FROM yourtable
```